# Send Notification after post published was working but stopped after the last WP update

Tags: php, posts, publish

I'm just wondering why this snippet stopped working! It was working before the last WordPress Update!

I'm using [DW Notifications](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-notifications/) plugin and work without any problem in another functions.

There are any explanation, Thanks.

```
function to_followers_only_notify( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );

        $followers = get_user_meta($author, '_pwuf_followers', true);
        $followers = array_unique($followers);

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('Published new post', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
        $link =  get_permalink($post->ID);
        if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'hitmag-list') ;
        }

        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);

        if ( !empty( $followers ) && is_array( $followers ) ) {

            $follower_ids = array();
            foreach( $followers as $follower ) {
                if ( is_numeric( $follower ) ) {

                    if(!$post->post_author || $post->post_author == $follower) continue;


                    $follower_ids[] = $follower;

                }
            }
            dwnotif_add_notification($follower_ids, $notif);
        }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'to_followers_only_notify', 10, 3 );
```

> **Update 1**

When I used `publish_post` action back to work again! But I need to avoid from everytime posts updated :(, any suggestions please, Thanks.

```
function to_followers_only_notify( $ID, $post ) {

    global $post;

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );

        $followers = get_user_meta($author, '_pwuf_followers', true);
        $followers = array_unique($followers);

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('Published new post', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
        $link =  get_permalink($post->ID);
        if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'hitmag-list') ;
        }

        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);

        if ( !empty( $followers ) && is_array( $followers ) ) {

            $follower_ids = array();
            foreach( $followers as $follower ) {
                if ( is_numeric( $follower ) ) {

                    if(!$post->post_author || $post->post_author == $follower) continue;

                    $follower_ids[] = $follower;

                }
            }
            dwnotif_add_notification($follower_ids, $notif);
        }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'to_followers_only_notify', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Update 1**. Perhaps you could compare the publish and modified dates and run your code only when they match, i.e. when the post is first published. Something along these lines,

```
function to_followers_only_notify( $ID, $post ) {

  $posted = strtotime( $post->post_date );
  $modified = strtotime( $post->post_modified );

  if ( $posted !== $modified ) {
    return;
  }

  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply, But sorry not working :(

Comment: Maybe DW Notification plugin issue? The first snippet was working perfectly :( With `transition_post_status` I don't know why stopped working!